# Why isn't my child div inheriting its width from the parent div?

Tags: html, css

This should be super simple. But the child will not inherit the width! Overflow:hidden works, but then the image is cropped terribly. When I try width:inherit it still does not work. Why isn't my child div inheriting the width of its wrapper?

```css
.project-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.project-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-wrapper">
  <div class="project-image">
    <img src="photo.jpg">
  </div>
  <p> Artist Website </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide `100%` to the image, not for the `div` since, `img` are `inline` elements.

```css
.project-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

.project-image img {
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-wrapper">
  <div class="project-image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <p> Artist Website </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So if my <div> had contained a block level element I would have been able to use the <div> inside a <div>?

Comment: Inline elements asks to specify `height` and `width` attribute to behave, so in your case case since you were trying for the `div`, it was fine but actual thing should happen for the `inline` element which is `img`. and btw `div` by default is `block` element.

Comment: But lets say my div had contained a <p> (block level element) would i still have to select the p, or could i just select the <div>?

Comment: @Manjuboyz they are actually `inline-block` elements, and they are elements that flow inline, but can be sized like block elements.

Comment: @Elizabeth `p` will flow like a `block` mean it takes the entire row so you don't have to consider the width values, but for `height` YES you have to specifically provide the values, you can do trial and error to find the differences. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/Lfrv48cx/3/ hope it gives you some clarity.. there are good articles on `layout` you should try those.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out! I had to select the image itself, not the image wrapper.

```
img{
width:100%
}
```

Comment: That's what my answer says!

Comment: I know, but check my comment above.